# Select groups which have more than one variable in them

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Simple question. Let's say I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
data.frame (species=c(a,a,b,c,c,d),dbh=c(5,4,7,1,3,6))
```

and I want to exclude the species b and d because they occur only once, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using either `base R` or using other packages.  With `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to `data.table` (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'species', `if` the number of rows is greater than 1 (`.N>1`) , we get the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, if(.N>1) .SD, species]
```

Or with `dplyr`, we use `filter` after the grouping.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>%
     group_by(species) %>%
     filter(n()>1)
```

---

The `base R` function `ave` can be used as well.  We group by 'species', get the `length`, convert to logical vector and `subset` the dataset.

```
 df1[with(df1, ave(dbh, species, FUN=length)>1),]
```

Or we can use `table` to get the frequency of elements in 'species'.  Find the `names` of the elements that have more than 1 count, use `%in%` to get a logical vector and then subset as before.

```
 tbl <- table(df1$species)>1
 df1[df1$species %in% names(tbl)[tbl],]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a lot. Seems like I have to learn that package.

Comment: I have to wait several minutes until I can accept an answer but now I did :)